# How to create DB record when Foriegn Key map to Auto generated Primary Key

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I already have a table (group_relation) with auto incremented integer as Primary Key and want to add a new table (relation_app) map to it.

- spring-boot = 2.7.14
- MySQL = 8

**MYSQL DDL**

```
CREATE TABLE group_relation (
    relation_id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    group_id VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    user_id VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (relation_id)
);

CREATE TABLE relation_app (
    auto_id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    relation_id int NOT NULL,
    app_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (auto_id)
);

ALTER TABLE relation_app ADD CONSTRAINT FK_GA_S1 FOREIGN KEY (relation_id) REFERENCES group_relation(relation_id);
```

**Java**

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "group_relation")
public class GroupRelationTable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer relationId;

    private String groupId;

    private String userId;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "groupRelationTable", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<RelationAppTable> userGroupAppAdminList;

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "relation_app")
public class RelationAppTable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer autoId;

    private Integer relationId;

    private String appName;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "groupRelationTable", referencedColumnName = "relationId", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private GroupRelationTable groupRelationTable;
}
```

**Test code**

```java
@Transactional
    public List<GroupRelationTable> createRelation() {
        List<GroupRelationTable> groupRelationTableList = new ArrayList<>();
        groupRelationTableList.add(GroupRelationTable.builder()
                .groupId("group-01")
                .userId("user-01")
                .userGroupAppAdminList(Collections.singletonList(
                        RelationAppTable.builder()
                        .appName("TEST_APP")
                        .build()
                        )
                )
                .build());

        relationRepository.saveAll(groupRelationTableList);

        return groupRelationTableList;
    }
```

**Error Cause**

```
STACK TRACE   = org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [null]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
    ...
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
    ...
Caused by: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: (conn=1627) Column 'relation_id' cannot be null
    ...
```

The error is probably cause by the missing relation_id when create record in new table. I have below questions

1. Is the design incorrect? (Foreign key map to Primary Key [auto incremented integer])
2. Should I split the insert statement to 2 (first to group_relation table, then to relation_app table with relation_id from first call)?

Comment: I can't comment on the Java code, but from a database point of view that all seems sensible - yes you should insert into `group_relation` first, retrieve the PK that's generated and include that value when you insert into `relation_app`

Answer (score 0):

You have a `relation_id` field that's specified as `NOT NULL`, so, whenever a `relation_app` record is created, you need to specify `relation_id`.

Your code

```
                        RelationAppTable.builder()
                        .appName("TEST_APP")
                        .build()
```

is set to create such a record, specifying `appName` to be `TEST_APP`, but you do not specify `relation_id` so this errors out.

A way to solve this would be to create the `GroupRelationTable` entity first and then create its child `RelationAppTable` and specify `relationId` as well.

Answer (score 0):

The error is due to the fact that you are trying to save a `GroupRelationTable` entity with a child of `RelationAppTable` while the `relationId` in child entity is not being set which is a foreign key and cannot be null.

When creating a new `RelationAppTable` entity, you should also set its parent `GroupRelationTable` so that the Hibernate sets the relationId foreign key when persisting the child entity.

An updated code

```
@Transactional
public List<GroupRelationTable> createRelation() {
    List<GroupRelationTable> groupRelationTableList = new ArrayList<>();
    
    GroupRelationTable groupRelation = GroupRelationTable.builder()
            .groupId("group-01")
            .userId("user-01")
            .build();
    
    RelationAppTable relationApp = RelationAppTable.builder()
            .appName("TEST_APP")
            .groupRelationTable(groupRelation)
            .build();
    
    groupRelation.setUserGroupAppAdminList(Collections.singletonList(relationApp));
    
    groupRelationTableList.add(groupRelation);

    relationRepository.saveAll(groupRelationTableList);

    return groupRelationTableList;
}
```

This ensures no need for splitting the insert statement to 2, as parent entity is saved Hibernate handles insertion of child entities and setting of foreign key.

NOTE: in `RelationAppTable` entity the `@JoinColumn` annotations `name` should match the column name in database not entity field name.

```
@JoinColumn(name = "relation_id", referencedColumnName = "relationId", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private GroupRelationTable groupRelationTable;
```

Comment: tried, same error. `Caused by: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: (conn=1764) Column 'relation_id' cannot be null`

Comment: This results from the annotations `insertable = false, updatable = false` which prevent hibernate from inserting or updating the relation_id, since the response above lets hibernate handle the relationship removing the attributes would work but this raises integrity concerns.

Best approach is to keep the attributes and save the `GroupRelationTable` entity and before saving the `RelationAppTable` entity.